# Concurrent queue consumption enigma in java

Tags: java, multithreading, opencv, java-8, java-stream

Trying to speed up my image processing using Java OpenCV, I tried to use a parallel stream to consume a queue of OpenCV `<Mat>`. If I time the algorithm and count what is left on the queue, I get incoherent results when processing the stream in parallel, but sequential computing results are correct. Since I used a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue()`, I thought I was all good with thread safety and asynchronicity, but apparently not. Would anyone know how to circumvent this problem?

Remarks:

- elements are still being put on the queue during its consumption
- I am running a 4 real (8 virtual) core processor

### Results with a sequential stream:

> frame collection start size (=production): 1455
>
> frame collection end size (=production - consumption): 1360
>
> resulting list size after algorithm run (=consumption): 100
>
> algorithm: 6956 ms

### Results with a parallel stream:

> frame collection start size (=production): 1455
>
> frame collection end size (=production - consumption): 440
>
> resulting list size after algorithm run (=consumption): 100
>
> algorithm: 9242 ms

### My code:

```
public class OvusculeTestConcurrent {

    public final static ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Mat> frameCollection = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Mat>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        final String path = "C:\\Users\\Raoul\\workspace\\aorta2\\ressource\\artery_src_for_dual.avi";
        long startAlgoTime = System.nanoTime();

        // Constitute a frame collection in async mode
        Capture cap = new Capture(path, frameCollection);
        new Thread(cap).start();
        Thread.sleep(3000); //leaves time to accumulate frames
        System.out.println("frame collection start size (=production): "+frameCollection.size());

        //Consumes the current queue in parallel/sequential
        List<ImagePlus> lm = Stream.generate(() -> {
                return frameCollection.poll();
            })
            .parallel() // comment to disable parallel computing
            .limit(100L)
            .map(img -> utils.PrepareImage(img,
                                    new Point(300, 250),
                                    new Point(450, 250),
                                    new Point(400, 400),
                                    0.25))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        //timing & printing the results
        long endAlgoTime = System.nanoTime();
        long algoDuration = (endAlgoTime - startAlgoTime)/1_000_000;  //divide by 1_000_000 to get milliseconds.
        System.out.println("frame collection end size (=production - consumption): "+frameCollection.size());
        System.out.println("resulting list size after algorithm run (=consumption): "+lm.size());
        System.out.println("algorithm: "+algoDuration+" ms");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: can you try frameCollection.parallelStream() instead and see if you still get the issue or not.

Comment: @I.K. I tried, and yes the issue persists... :-(

Comment: @I.K. The modified does not seem to consume the queue at all. It seems that if I use `.stream()` or `.parallelstream()` the images do get processed (`lm` has elements), but those elements are not removed from the queue... `frame collection start size (=production): 1454
frame collection end size (=production - consumption): 1460
resulting list size after algorithm run (=consumption): 100
algorithm: 7039 ms`

Comment: Yes that is expected. The stream operations will not and should not modify the source which in this case is the concurrent linked queue. Doing so will cause erroneous results. The operations on the source should be read only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things going on with the code that caught my eye.

First, creating a stream from a using `Stream.generate` is on the right track. It's preferable to just calling `queue.stream()`, which will return a stream consisting of only *the current contents* of the queue. You say that elements are being added to the queue during processing, so that won't work.

One problem is with the code that generates the stream like this (edited for clarity):

```
Stream.generate(() -> queue.poll())
```

The problem is with the `poll` method, which is defined as follows:

> Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, or returns null if this queue is empty.

It may be that when the stream is run in parallel, the stream's threads can drain the queue faster than elements are produced and inserted into the queue. If this occurs, the queue will empty out at a certain point and the stream will become populated with `null` elements returned by `poll`.

I'm not sure what `PrepareImage` does when handed a null, but it seems to pass something through to the output, which is why you always get 100 elements in the destination list.

The alternative is to use a `BlockingQueue` implementation and use the `take` method, something like

```
Stream.generate(() -> queue.take())
```

This will avoid injecting nulls into the stream. I'm not sure which `BlockingQueue` implementation you should use, but I'd advise you to investigate one with a size bound. If your producer outstrips your consumers, an unbounded queue could expand to fill all available memory.

Unfortunately, `BlockingQueue.take()` throws `InterruptedException` so you can't use it in a simple lambda. You'll have to figure out what to do upon interrupts. Maybe return a dummy element or something.

Another issue is that the `limit` method imposes a limit on the number of elements that are passed *downstream*, but in parallel streams, the multiple threads may opportunistically pull more than that number of elements from the stream for processing. These are buffered up by the `limit` operation until its limit is reached, at which time the stream processing terminates. Any elements pulled from the stream source and buffered when the limit is reached are simply discarded. That might be why over 1,000 elements are pulled from the queue but only 100 elements end up in the result list.

(But even in the sequential case the numbers don't add up. I don't think the same thing could be going on, with buffered elements being discarded when the limit is reached. Perhaps it's because of the additional elements being produced during processing?)

If you can live with elements being discarded, then a parallel stream fed by `queue.take()` might work; otherwise, a different approach is required.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issue and could not find solution in web. Come up with my own `Spliterator`, looks like SpliteratorWithUnknownSize does not support parallelism (Didn't research that, just saw that all processing done in the same thread). Here it is:

```
public class QueueDrainSpliterator<T> implements Spliterator<T> {

    private final BlockingQueue<T> elements;

    public QueueDrainSpliterator(BlockingQueue<T> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        T el = elements.poll();
        if (el != null) {
            action.accept(el);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<T> trySplit() {
        if (!elements.isEmpty()) {
            BlockingQueue<T> split = new LinkedBlockingQueue<T>();
            elements.drainTo(split, (int) Math.ceil(elements.size() / 2d));
            return new QueueDrainSpliterator<T>(split);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long estimateSize() {
        return elements.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int characteristics() {
        return Spliterator.NONNULL | Spliterator.CONCURRENT;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
StreamSupport.stream(new QueueDrainSpliterator<>(events), true)
                     .forEach(consumer);
```

It will iterate over resources while they are in queue. If queue is empty it will finish. If you need to wait for elements to be generated you could try use `elements.poll(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`